# How do closures work in PHP (If at all)?

Tags: php

```
function outer_function() {
  $nid = 3;

    function exists($var) {
    print $nid;
    return $var->nid == $nid;
    }   

    $a_filtered_array = array_filter($an_array, "exists");
}
```

I'm trying to filter this array using a variable that's defined in the outer function, but the variable is not defined. This would work in JS. What am I doing wrong here? How would I accomplish this in PHP?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: What version of PHP is this? At least 5.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write this (correctly) as:

```
function outer_function() {
  $nid = 3

    $a_filtered_array = array_filter($an_array, function ($var) use ($nid) {
        print $nid;
        return $var->nid == $nid;
    });
}
```

You can't just pass a string containing the function's name. You could also write

```
function outer_function() {
  $nid = 3
  $exists =  function ($var) use ($nid) {
        print $nid;
        return $var->nid == $nid;
    }
    $a_filtered_array = array_filter($an_array, $exists);
}
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php for in-depth on the syntax and semantics.

Comment: a little correction... aren't you forgetting of "use"? $exists =  function ($var) use ($nid) {...

Comment: Ah cool. I tried to use an anonymous function but missed the use part. Thanks.

Comment: Crap I just discovered the server I'm working on uses 5.2.something and doesn't support anonymous functions. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Joren don't use anonymous functions :) It's very easy to use PHP without them, you'll just have to avoid using any of the higher order functions like `array_map()` or `array_filter()`. If you really want to use them, though, you might be able to install a newer version of PHP.

Answer (score 1):

They are called **anonymous functions**, check the docs

*That's* how they work:

```
function outer_function()
{
   $nid = 3;

   $x=function ($var) {
     print $nid;
     return $var->nid == $nid;
   }; 

   $a_filtered_array = array_filter($an_array, $x);

}
```

And *this* approach too would have worked in JS
(and is actually more explicit about *what's really happening under the hood*)

```
function x() {
  var w=function() {alert("foo")}
  w()
}
```